# how to automatically assign value of textview to the string

Tags: java, android

i want to assign the editext value to the string automatically

when i click the button it assign but not automatically

```
private void OverValidation()
    {

        if (!noOfOvers.equals("0"))
        {
            noOfOvers=chooseOverEdttext.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose no of overs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

i want when i type the text in edit text it assign value to the string at same time

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `TextView#addTextChangedListener` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))).
It's pretty easy.

```
chooseOverEdttext.addTextChangedListener(
   new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(
              final CharSequence text,
              final int start, 
              final int before, 
              final int count) {
         final String noOfOvers = text.toString();
         // Process your String, or use CharSequence directly
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(
              final CharSequence text, 
              final int start, 
              final int count, 
              final int after) { }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
         // Editable represents the changed text. If you need to process
         // the inserted text and modify it, you can apply these modifications
         // here, directly to the Editable instance. Be carefult as it might be called recursively.
      }
   }
);
```

If you use `TextWatcher`(s) a lot, you might also want to create an `Adapter`, which is a base class which implement these three methods as no-op. Then you'll be able to override only the one you're interested in. A lot cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability). It has a functionality for connecting views and data sources.

For example, you can have a ObservableString inside your Activity:

`ObservableField<String> noOfOvers = new ObservableField<String>()`

Then, inside your xml you should add a binding to this data:

```
<layout 
  xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools=”http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <data>
    <import type="android.databinding.ObservableField"/>
    <variable name="noOfOvers" type="ObservableField<String>"
  </data>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:orientation=”vertical”>
    <EditText
      android:layout_width=”match_parent”
      android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
      android:text=”@{noOfOvers}”/>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

For now, once you've made changes inside the EditText, it's value will be automatically assigned to the noOfOvers variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add change listener to your edittext then set string to your edittext or whatever

```
youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

 @Override    
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after) {
 }

 @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
   int before, int count) {
    if(s.length() != 0)
    field2.setText("");
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get automatic updates by using `addTextChangedListener` on `EditText` . Here is sample.

```
x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x);
x.addTextChangedListener(
new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String tmp = editable.toString();
                if(!tmp.equals(""))
                    h = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding textchangeListner to the editText.

Here is the proper implementation of your the code:

```
 chooseOverEdttext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            setString();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
 });

  private void setString(){
    String overs=chooseOverEdttext.getText().toString(); 
    if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(overs)||overs.equals("0")))
    {
        noOfOvers=overs;
    }


  }
```

just copy and paste this code in place of your current code